# How to cause a side-effect to run whenever a list argument changes

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable to show movie posters and a carouselCurrentIndex to index different elements in the list. I have two buttons that on Click will update the index to show the next and previous movie posters in the list using the scroll functions below.

```
fun CustomCarousel(
    movies: List<Movie>
) {
     var carouselCurrentIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
     
     fun scrollNext(){
        if (carouselCurrentIndex == (movies.size -1)){
            carouselCurrentIndex = 0
        }else{
            carouselCurrentIndex = carouselCurrentIndex + 1
        }
    }

    fun scrollPrevious(){
        if (carouselCurrentIndex == 0){
            carouselCurrentIndex = (movies.size -1)
        }else{
            carouselCurrentIndex = carouselCurrentIndex - 1
        }
    }
    <Code to show current poster (movie[carouselCurrentIndex].poster),
     Buttons to call scrollNext and scrollPrevious>

}
```

I want to reset the value of carouselCurrentIndex to 0 whenever the list of movies is updated, i.e. whenever a new item is added/removed to the list.

The CustomCarousel is called like this from parent composable

```
CustomCarousel(viewModel.bannerItemList)
```

and inside viewModel it's defined as

```
var bannerItemList = mutableStateListOf<Movie>()
```

Changes to the list are done using functions

```
viewModel.bannerItemList.clear()
viewModel.bannerItemList.add(it)
```

I have tried using a couple of side effects within CustomCarousel composable but to no use

1.

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = movies){
  carouselCurrentIndex = 0
}
```

2. 

```
val listSizeKey = remember {
    mutableStateOf(movies.size)
}
LaunchedEffect(key1 = listSizeKey) {
    carouselCurrentIndex = 0
}
```

The list is getting updated properly but LaunchedEffects won't trigger. Can anyone point out what's wrong with my approach and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To reset the remember state in a Compose function when the size of the list parameter changes, you can use a key parameter with a unique value for each list size. This will cause the remember block to be re-executed and the state to be reset.

Here is an example of how you can use this approach:

```
@Composable
fun CustomCarousel(
    movies: List<Movie>
) {
     val rememberKey = movies.size
     var carouselCurrentIndex by remember(rememberKey) { mutableStateOf(0) }
     //...
}
```

In this example, `rememberKey` is set to the size of the list parameter. This ensures that the remember block is re-executed and the state is reset whenever the size of the list changes.